# Using Spring Data,Mongodb, how can I avoid Duplicate vertices error

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I get the error in one of the polygons i am importing.

```
Write failed with error code 16755 and error message 'Can't extract geo keys: { _id: "b9c5ac0c-e469-4b97-b059-436cd02ffe49", _class: .... ] Duplicate vertices: 0 and 15'
```

Full stack Trace: https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/927aa14e8d1e42d7cf516dc25b6ebb66#file-stacktrace

[GeoJson MultiPolygon I am importing using Spring Data MongoDB](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/boundaries-io/932fec8d041aae6dd42ab0104318127c/raw/55b61fe99da3a00aa4b2c0f26efbbcfdb9632370/multipolygon)

```
public class MyPolgyon {

    @Id
    String id;

    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type=GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    GeoJsonPoint position;

    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type=GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    GeoJsonPoint location;

    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type=GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    GeoJsonPolygon polygon;





public static GeoJsonPolygon generateGeoJsonPolygon(List<LngLatAlt> coordinates) {
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for ( LngLatAlt  point: coordinates) {                          
                org.springframework.data.geo.Point dataPoint = new org.springframework.data.geo.Point( point.getLongitude() ,point.getLatitude());              
                points.add(dataPoint);          
            }   
        return new  GeoJsonPolygon(points);
    }
```

How can i avoid this error in Java?

I can load the geojson fine in http://geojson.io

here is the GEOJSON: https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/4719bfc386c3728b36be10af29860f4c#file-rol-ca-part1-geojson

removal of duplicates using:

```
for (com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate coordinate : geometry.getCoordinates()) {
    Point lngLatAtl = new Point(coordinate.x, coordinate.y);
    boolean isADup = points.contains(lngLatAtl);
    if ( !notDup ){
        points.add(lngLatAtl);
    }else{
        LOGGER.debug("Duplicate,  [" + lngLatAtl.toString() +"] index["  + count  +"]");
    }
    count++;
}
```

Logging:

```
2017-10-27 22:38:18 DEBUG TestBugs:58 - Duplicate,  [Point [x=-97.009868, y=52.358242]] index[15]
2017-10-27 22:38:18 DEBUG TestBugs:58 - Duplicate,  [Point [x=-97.009868, y=52.358242]] index[3348]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you have duplicate vertex at index 0 and index 1341 for 2nd polygon.

```
[ -62.95859676499998, 46.20653318300003 ]
```

The insertion fails when Mongo db is trying to build the 2d sphere index for the document. Remove the coordinate at index 1341 and you should be able to persist successfully.

You just have to cleanse the data when you find the error.
You can write a small program to read the error from mongo db and provide the update back to the client. Client can act on those messages and try again the request.

More information on geo errors can be found [`here`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14508).
You can look at the code here for [`GeoParser`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/geo/geoparser.cpp#L582) to find how/what errors are generated. For the specific error you got you can take a look here [`GeoParser`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/geo/geoparser.cpp#L223). This [`error`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/third_party/s2/s2loop.cc#L124) is generated by S2 library that Mongodb uses for validation.